# How to login to multiple IP addresses saved into a file with EXPECT script, while I have a username and password set before login?

Tags: expect

How to login to multiple UNIX machines whose IP addresses are saved into a file with EXPECT script, while I have a username and password set before login?

Answer (score 0):

roughly:

```tcl
set fh [open ip_file.txt r]
while {[gets $fh ip] != -1} {
    spawn ssh $user@$ip
    expect "assword:"
    send -- $pass\r
    # do stuff
    send -- exit\r
    expect eof
}
close $fh
```

In this scenario, you would be better off to set up keys for each machine ([ssh-keygen](http://man.cx/ssh-keygen), [ssh-copy-id](http://man.cx/ssh-copy-id), [ssh-agent](http://man.cx/ssh-agent), [ssh-add](http://man.cx/ssh-add)). Then you can use a simple shell script

```sh
while read ip; do

ssh $user@$ip << END_SSH
# don't need the password
# do stuff
END_SSH

done < ip_file.txt
```